# YoutubePlayerFragment showing device not supported?

Tags: android, android-youtube-api

I had integrated YoutubePlayerFragment in my application to show youtube videos.
However from 21st april I get error on saying device is not supported.

Please visit youtube.com/devicesupport

Any one facing same issue?

How can i resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

From Official website

[Certain older YouTube apps will no longer be supported after April 2015](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/6098135?p=yt_devicesupport&hl=en&rd=1)

> As we upgrade the YouTube Data API to bring more features, we’ll begin shutting down the old version on April 20, 2015. This will result in the current YouTube app not working on certain *device models from 2012 and older*

Comment: i know that.. i am asking isnt there backward compatibility.

Comment: Need to wait. till now no new about that.

Answer (score 0):

I am answering this question because after some frustration it was not on android api related issue but Gdata youtube api i was using was returning wrong results.

Now its fixed.