# How to play youtube video using Youtube Data api v3 Android?

Tags: android, android-youtube-api

Few days back I asked question [Youtube API v2 not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29787391/youtubeplayerfragment-showing-device-not-supported) So as per youtube they have deprecated and all application and websites using this v2 api wont work at all. As they told to migrate to v3 there are any good example or documents for android. I have youtube url with video id. I just want to play videos using this api

Answer (score 0):

You can use Video ID to play video...

Use YouTubePlayerView for that...

Let me show you a example which will makes everything clear....

below is a class which contains a YouTubePlayerView..

```
public class Play_youtube_video extends YouTubeBaseActivity implements YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener
{

YouTubePlayerView   video_player;
public static String        VIDEO_ID    = "";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // HIDE THE KEYBOARD
    getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);

    // TITLE BAR DISABLES AND FULL SCREEN IMPLEMENTATION
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_play_youtube_video);

    try
    {




        System.out.println("youtube----VIDEO_ID---->" + VIDEO_ID);

        video_player = (YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.youtubeplayerview_full_screen);
        video_player.initialize(GlobalConstant.YOUTUBE_APIKEY, Play_youtube_video.this);

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch(OutOfMemoryError e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}

@Override
public void onInitializationFailure(Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult result)
{
    GlobalUtills.showToast("Youtube player not found.", Play_youtube_video.this);

}

@Override
public void onInitializationSuccess(Provider provider, YouTubePlayer player, boolean wasRestored)
{
    if( !wasRestored )
    {
        player.loadVideo(Youtube_VIDEO_ID);
        // player.setFullscreen(true);
        // player.play();
    }

}

public void closeYoutube(View v)
{
    Play_youtube_video.this.finish();
}
```

}

Comment: This is already code i used but recent shutdown on api v2 by youtube causing this mayhem

Comment: are you sure .. i am getting error as devicenot supported. Please visit www.youtube.com/devicesupport when i play video.. What jars you are using

Comment: i m sure about this and you can check a complete working tutorial here ---->  http://www.androidhive.info/2014/12/how-to-play-youtube-video-in-android-app/      ,it will help..

Comment: This is posted on 26th, Dec 2014.
I too had code working until api v2 got deprecated on 21st april 2015

Comment: and remember You need to run version 4.2.16 of the mobile YouTube app (or higher) to use the API.....

Comment: I have latest version of youtube which as per play store says 10.14.56

Answer (score -1):

I am answering this question because after some frustration it was not on android api related issue but Gdata youtube api i was using was returning wrong results.

Now its fixed.